# CSS hover one div effects that div plus another

Tags: html, css

I have read almost 15 questions in regards to this problem, but do not find one that helps with what I want.

Let's say I have 5 div's stacked in a pyramid fashion, with the one in the middle on top, and the two on the side at the bottom.

What I want is if you hover over `div1` OR `div5`, that both will come to the foreground. And then also if you hover over `div2` OR `div4` that the two of them will come to the foreground. I have tried many things, but usually if you hover over one, the other comes forward but not both of them. Or what I have now is where I hover over a parent div, both come forward, but when I actually hover over one of the div's, nothing happens.

Here is the code that I have now.

```css
#stack1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#boks3,
#boks1,
#boks2,
#boks4,
#boks5 {
  background-color: #ff3333;
  width: 32%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 33.5%;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#boks1 {
  background-color: #ff6666;
  margin-left: 2%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks2 {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  margin-left: 17%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks5 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin-left: 65%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: right;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks4 {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
  margin-left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  height: 300px;
}
#stack1:hover + #boks1,
#stack1:hover ~ #boks5 {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="boks3">

</div>

<div id="stack1"></div>
<div id="boks1">

</div>
<div id="boks5">

</div>


<div id="stack2">
  <div id="boks2">

  </div>
  <div id="boks4">

  </div>
</div>
```

I would  really like to do this in CSS, seeing that I am using it in Angular 2 framework and do not want to add jQuery to the Angular 2 framework.

Kind regards

Comment: Where is your div1 and div5 in this example? all i see is a boks-div?

Comment: CSS can only select to the right and downwards, but not to the left or upwards. So hover on f.e. your `boks5` can never have any influence on the `boks1` before it. Not saying it is _absolutely impossible_ (depending on specifics and how the structure could possibly be changed; you say something about a “pyramid”, but your example does not seem to reflect that) - but I think with JS you will achieve this much easier.

Comment: Did you tried to use classes ?

Comment: The pyramid is basically boks3 that is on the top, and below it is boks2 and boks4 on which boks3 stands, and below all three of them, at the bottom is boks1 and boks5. (boks here also means div). This can be seen by looking at the "z-index" in every div id. When you hover over a boks it moves to the top, to z-index 4.

Comment: hmmm, I have soemhow actually not thought of classes DomeTune, let me try and see if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wrap `boks1` and `boks5` into `stack1` as well as `boks2` and `boks4` into `stack2`. When you hover on any of `boks`es stack:hover event will fire up.

```css
#stack1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#boks3,
#boks1,
#boks2,
#boks4,
#boks5 {
  background-color: #ff3333;
  width: 32%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 33.5%;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#boks1 {
  background-color: #ff6666;
  margin-left: 2%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks2 {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  margin-left: 17%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks5 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin-left: 65%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: right;
  height: 300px;
}
#boks4 {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
  margin-left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  height: 300px;
}
#stack1:hover #boks1,
#stack1:hover #boks5 {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 4;
}
#stack2:hover #boks2,
#stack2:hover #boks4 {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="boks3">
</div>

<div id="stack1">
 <div id="boks1">
 </div>
 <div id="boks5">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="stack2">
  <div id="boks2">
  </div>
  <div id="boks4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Banzay, that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!